# How long until a bean chulent is totally cooked (mevushal kol tzorko)?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food, shiurim-measurements, cooking-bishul

My son has started raiding the chulent Friday night.  To be able to return the chulent crock pot back to the casing, everything must be fully cooked.  I rarely cook with beans, but would like to try some limas or garbanzos.  How long does it take to cook unsoaked beans on low?  I'm sure every crock pot is different, but would appreciate a range of possibilities.

If you know other variables, I would appreciate that as well. (Various beans, on high, soaked, crock pot size, etc.)

Comment: Sounds like a case for [science](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/dont-be-afraid-to-use-the-science/)!

Comment: It may be worth defining "kol tzorko" precisely in lay terms and asking on http://cooking.stackexchange.com/ , then reporting back to here.

Comment: Here are some possible sources on Cooking.SE. They mostly talk about soaked beans. http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15753/undercooked-beans-in-chili http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19086/cooking-red-kidney-beans http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16020/how-to-make-kidney-beans-tender http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9891/if-a-recipe-calls-for-canned-beans-and-i-want-to-use-dried-beans-what-do-i-need

Comment: Thanks, @IsaacMoses, that helped.  I'll post some of the information.  I had a hava amina someone was going to tell me I was on the wrong SE!

Comment: Is this on topic?

Answer (score 2):

According to zanlok's comment on [this](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15753/undercooked-beans-in-chili) Cooking SE question, unsoaked beans need to simmer for 12-18 hours and is consistent with Ray's answer of "overnight or even into the day".  Practically, one would need to start the chulent Thursday night to be able to raid it on Friday night.

Ray continues to estimate the simmering time for pre-soaked beans at a mere 2 - 2 1/2 hours.  Pre-soaking sounds like the way to go.

Thank you Isaac for doing the research.

Comment: Maybe the experts at cooking.se have higher standards than I do, but IIRC I've thrown unsoaked beans into vegetable soup, eaten them after a couple of hours' simmering, and they were AFAICT fine.

Comment: @msh210 I may have to make a weekday chulent and find out!

Comment: @YDK good idea.

Comment: It definitely does not take anywhere near that long in a crockpot. I've tried hundreds of times.